# GL Studio project with compile errors in gl.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a VS solution with 20+ [GL Studio](http://www.disti.com/products/gl-studio/) projects in it. I recently upgraded these project from GL Studio 3.2 to version 4.4. All of the projects build except three of them. These three projects give a ton of compiler errors in `gl.h` when I try to build. I know from other SO questions (e.g., [VC++ compile errors when including gl.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430413/vc-compile-errors-when-including-gl-h)) that `windows.h` must be included before `gl.h` but since GL Studio automatically generates the source code this should already be done and it is being done in the projects that build.

The interesting thing is that the other GL Studio projects in the same solution are also including `gl.h` and they build just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WIN32 must be defined in the Visual Studio project settings in the Preprocessor Definitions as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080279/1454861) by André Caron's comment.

If WIN32 is absent or undefined, `windows.h` will not be included and `gl.h` will not compile.